# why nolock is important while querying on database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Woking on a huge database I was extracting huge amount of data. for example my query is

```
select * from temp
```

it was causing errors for my application users then I realised that I was because my query was taking too long time to extract data.

then I modified my query with

```
select * from temp with(nolock)
```

and then everything is smooth. somebody please explain why nolock is such important.

Answer (score 5):

`NOLOCK` **overrides** the rules that ensure that the data you read from your database is consistent and respects [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) rules (***A***tomicity, **C**onsistency, **I**solation, **D**urability).

If you run a query **without** `NOLOCK` then you will always get the same result back (*assuming nobody else deletes or updates any of the data in the meantime*).

If you run a query **WITH** `NOLOCK` twice or more, your results may vary.

`NOLOCK` actually means that you tell the DB to return the data it can read, no matter if it has been commited to the database or not.

So, in conclusion and in short: `NOLOCK` is important if you want **accurate** data or not. If you want *just data*, then you could use `NOLOCK`, but it's generally not a very good idea.

Comment: Your answer seems to say the opposite of what you mean. `NOLOCK` does not ensure data is consistent. Getting consistent data is the default behaviour.

Comment: @hvd You are right, it's really early and haven't had my coffee. Will correct, thank you for your vigilence.

Comment: The answer says it overrides the rules of getting consistent data. So, it means NOLOCK get us inconsistent data. So, the answer is perfect

Answer (score 1):

When you say WITH NOLOCK and execute your query then it is like using READ UNCOMMITED data. So you are ready to read the uncommitted data as well which can be rolled back. So you are in risk of reading the dirty data.

You can refer:

- [SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx)
- [THE SIDE EFFECT OF NOLOCK](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/)

Answer (score 1):

The WITH (nolock) hint is an explicit command directed at a specific table or view used to set the transaction isolation level against the table or tables within a view for a query. Once issued, locks will not be used against the data within the table. The advantage to this is there is no chance a deadlock will occur against any other queries running against the table. The other indirect advantage is that less memory will be used in order to hold locks against that data

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOLOCK for queries used in MIS Reports, where some changes in data doesn't affect the management decisions.

But you should not use NOLOCK for operational queries and operationl reports. which could impact the operations and are risky